# Using path-strings as index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, raw

I am trying to create a dataframe with filepaths as index:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
pathnames = []
for i in range(5):
    pathnames.append(os.path.join('a',str(i)))

print(pathnames)
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pathnames)
df[pathnames[0]]
```

When using this example I get a key-error as `pathnames[0]` is interpreted as `a\\0` (as when printed) but not as `a\0`. I expect the problem to be hidden in the raw string formatting.
Can someone explain and help?
pandas version tested: 0.24.2 and 1.1.0

Comment: `df[pathnames[0]]` selects columns, not indices. if you pass `df.loc[pathnames[0]]` you get a result

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guessed it was something trivial but I did not think the right way

Answer (score 0):

Use loc or iloc

```
import os
import pandas as pd
pathnames = []
for i in range(5):
    pathnames.append(os.path.join('a',str(i)))

print(pathnames)
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pathnames)
print(df.loc['a/0'])
```